# Block level element appearing to right side instead of beneath other div

Tags: html, css

What is the scope of div element. Can any other element use the unused space in div element?

In the below example `continue reading` block should be displayed below div(class="post_text") but its not happening like that. please explain why.
I have this code

```css
.content {
  background-color: #FF8000;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
}

p span {
  background-color: #E8F827;
}

.post_text img {
  float: left;
}

.cnread {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="post">

  <div class="post_text">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Football_Pallo_valmiina-cropped.jpg" width="200" alt="">

    <p>Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <a class="cnread" href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is output

[image]

I want this output

[image]

I want `continue reading` below.
How to do it?

Comment: could ypu please reproduce the issue in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)..

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because of you have image floated left. You need to clear content, so 'Continue Reading` will begin from new line.
This should fix it
Html and CSS code:

```css
.content {
  background-color: #FF8000;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
}

p span {
  background-color: #E8F827;
}

.post_text img {
  float: left;
}

.cnread {
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="post">

  <div class="post_text">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" alt="">

    <p>Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos </p>
  </div>

  <div class='clear'>
    <a class="cnread" href="">Continue Reading</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @martinho Well in general it forces next elements not to wrap around floated elements. I advise you to check this article to get clearer understanding - https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 1):

Give the "continue reading" `<div>` a class name and then add this CSS:

```
    .classname {
        clear: both;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

Also, remove the `float: right` style from the anchor